# Project 2013 Daily requirements Summary

Tags: project

I'm trying to figure out how to show a daily requirement for our construction projects, these projects are to large and not feasible to assign individual resources.

So here is what I have, custom number column is a formula that shows work\duration this tells me the number of workers required to complete that task over the planned duration.

Now what I'm looking to do is have a report that gives me the daily summary of the required workers for that day or the average for the week.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want so see your daily requirements, you can just change the view.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-timescale-in-a-view-3c81c793-a5fd-4339-bb10-3c9960b8c55f

```
"On the View menu, select a view that uses a timescale, such as the Gant
  Chart, Task Usage, or Resource Graph view.

 On the Format menu, click Timescale, and then click the Top Tier, Middle
 Tier, or Bottom Tier tab.

 In the Show list, select the number of tiers that you want to display 
 in the timescale. By default, two tiers are displayed.

 On the tab for the displayed timescale tier, in the Units box, select
  the time unit that you want to use. The types of units range from years to  
 minutes.

 In the Label list, select the label format that you want to use to 
 display the time unit.

 In the Count box, type or select a number to specify the frequency 
 of unit labels on the timescale tier."
```

For example, if the unit is weeks, and you type 2, then the timescale tier is separated into 2-week segments."

Comment: Thanks Alex but not quite what I need, I think this needs to be a report or grouping ultimately. Every task has a calculated daily requirement I just need a way to Summarize for each day what that requirement is.        In the end I need to be able to have a line chart this showing the labor curve over the duration of the project

Comment: Ok I understand your question much better now.  I do not have direct access to MS Project 2013, only through virtural machine hosted remotely.  Unfortunately working with it is painfully slow, but if I have some time I will try to see if I can get you a better answer.